# Ghostscript converting PostScript to PDF seems to ignore the page size / BoundingBox

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert, postscript

I have created a PostScript file from a TIFF image using ImageMagick.

The command-line I am using is:

```
convert input.tif[0] -density 600 -alpha Off -size 5809x9408 -depth 16 intermediate.ps
```

This takes my input tiff image (just the main image, and not the thumbnail via using [0]) and creates a .ps file from the bitmap.

When I look at the header of my PostScript file, I can see that it has the correct page size:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Creator: (ImageMagick)
%%Title: (intermediate.ps)
%%CreationDate: (2017-05-22T08:43:44+10:00)
%%BoundingBox: -0 -0 697 1129
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 697.08 1129
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 1
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%Pages: 1
%%EndComments
```

Yet, when I use GhostScript to convert this to a PDF, unless I go to a lot of trouble to specify otherwise, gs is cropping it and putting it on a US Letter sized page.

```
gs -dPDFA=1 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sDefaultRGBProfile=AdobeRGB1998.icc -dOverrideICC -sOutputFile=output.pdf -r600 -P PDFA_def.ps intermediate.ps
```

When I open the resulting PDF, the crop box is 612 x 792 pt which is US Letter. It should be 697 x 1129 pt, the size of the Bounding Box in the PostScript file.

I have created a custom .joboptions file using Acrobat Distiller that sets image compression and the like, and in this file if I specify the page size at the end, then the resulting PDF comes out the correct size:

```
<<
  /HWResolution [600 600]
  /PageSize [697.080 1128.960]
>> setpagedevice
```

Now this isn't a huge issue for a one-off conversion, but I have to convert a large number of images and I don't want to set the page size manually for every single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines you quote above are **comments** and, from the comments present, suggest that this is an **EPS** file, not a PostScript program.

The main difference is that EPS is 'encapsulated' which means its intended to be placed verbatim inside a PostScript program. The enclosing program contains the intelligence regarding the media size, and arranges to set the context such that the EPS is scaled, rotated, translated so that it fits appropriately on the media.

In order to do this successfully, the EPS file must follow certain rules; in particular it must not set any media size itself (because that would mess with the enclosing program).

So it seems likely to me that what you have is an EPS file which does not request any media size at all. So its hardly surprising that you have to tell Ghostscript what you want to do with it.

Now in order for the enclosing program to place the EPS it needs to know its characteristics, the size and shape of the content. That's what the comments are for. Ordinarily an EPS file is read by an application (eg MS Word, LibreOffice etc) which parses out those comments and uses the information when generating the final PostScript program. The reason an EPS uses comments to store this information is precisely so that it has no effect on the actual content of the EPS and so the entire EPS can be included without further processing by the application.

The short answer is that if you read the Ghostscript documentation [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Use.htm#EPS_parameters) you will find descriptions of the `EPSCrop` and `EPSFitPage` command line switches which will do all the work for you.

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to write up a detailed and comprehensive answer. I was under the impression that ImageMagick was giving me a full PostScript file, not an EPS. I did try using -dEPSCrop but seemed to still give me the same US Letter page size.
I will remove my hard-coded page size definitions from my .joboptions file and try converting again with gs using -dEPSCrop.

Comment: I can look at the actual file if you make it available somewhere, I'm 'guessing' rather when I say its an EPS based simply on the comments, because to the interpreter comments are ignored, so you can put anything you like in there. Just because the comments 'look like' an EPS file, doesn't mean it is an EPS file.....

Comment: I've stripped the image data from the file (as it was over 300 MB) leaving just the other PostScript code behind...
I've uploaded it to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/HTrRygga
Cheers!

Comment: OK so it isn't an EPS file, it is a PostScript file, but it makes no media size request. Since the comments are just comments any PostScript printer will just print it on whatever the default media is. Since that'll most often be US Letter or A4, the content will be truncated. You could either carry on with your joboptions approach, or write a DSC parser to read the comments and execute a media size request from them. Ghostscript won't do it 'out of the box' though, because by default it ignores comments. Really IM ought to send a media request.

Comment: FWIW you could use libtiff instead, or if you are truly desperate, I did (a long time ago) write a PostScript program to read TIFF files directly. Someone dug up a Google groups link and posted it here a while back, I'll reproduce it again for completeness https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.postscript/xLMTVNzGNXQ/g7gItvNwPEIJ

Comment: Thank you Ken, you've really gone over and above to help out. Now I know why it's not working when I use EPSCrop or no page size.
It's strange that IM does it this way, I will look into seeing if there are any options in IM that tell it to actually set the media size.
I'm working with a php script to handle batch processing these files - at the moment I'm looking up the size of the image and then writing that out into a joboptions file before each image is converted but I may look into using tiff2ps from TIFF Tools - I'm very picky about compression and icc profiles so will need to test.